# React-Redux : How to dispatch async actions and sync actions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I started coding a web interface to manage my server's files using React/Redux.
I now have a page which requests my API to get files list as JSON.

It works well, I got my page with a list of all my files from server.
But the select file action fails with the following error:

> TypeError : _this2.props.selectFile is not a function

Here's my code :

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {Provider, connect} from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import activeFileReducer from './reducers/reducer-active-file';
import dataListReducer from './reducers/reducer-data';

const reducer = combineReducers({
    datalist: dataListReducer, 
    activefile: activeFileReducer
})
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore)
let store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer);
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('table'));
```

datalist-reducer

```
export default function datalist (state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "FETCH_REQUEST":
            return state;
        case "FETCH_SUCCESS": 
            return action.payload || [];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

active-file-reducer

```
export default function activefile (state= {}, action){
        switch(action.type){
            case "FILE_SELECTED":
                return action.payload;
            default:
                return state;
        }

    }
```

actions/index.js

```
export const selectFile = (file) => {
    return {
        type: "FILE_SELECTED",
        payload: file
    }
}


export const fetchDataRequest = () =>{
    return {
      type: "FETCH_REQUEST"
    }
}

export const fetchDataSuccess = (payload) => {
    return {
        type: "FETCH_SUCCESS",
        payload
    }
}

export const fetchDataError = () => {
    return {
        type: "FETCH_ERROR"
    }
}
```

data-list-container

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {fetchDataRequest, fetchDataSuccess, fetchDataError, selectFile} from '../actions/index';

class DataList extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchDataWithRedux()

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <ul>
                {
                    this.props.datalist && 
                    this.props.datalist.map((item, key) =>{
                        return(
                            <li key={key} onClick={() => this.props.selectFile(item)}>{item.title}</li>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        )       
    }
}


function fetchDataWithRedux() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(fetchDataRequest());
        return fetchData().then(([response, json]) =>{
            console.log(response);
            if(response.status === 200){
            dispatch(fetchDataSuccess(json))
            dispatch(selectFile())
    }
    else{
        dispatch(fetchDataError())
        dispatch(selectFile())
    }
    })
}
}

function fetchData() {
const URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/deposit/view";
return fetch(URL, { method: 'GET'})
    .then( response => Promise.all([response, response.json()]));
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        datalist: state.datalist
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchDataWithRedux})(DataList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not passing `selectFile` function to component in props, here:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchDataWithRedux})(DataList);
```

Pass `selectFile` in the same way as you are passing `fetchDataWithRedux`, Use this:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchDataWithRedux, selectFile})(DataList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use selectFile instead of binding it to props when you have  imported those to your component.

```
<li key={key} onClick={() => selectFile(item)}>{item.title}</li>
```

Just remove this.props. prefixed to selectFile